# linear layout doesn't fit to screen size

Tags: android, android-linearlayout

Why the linear layout inside a scroll view doesn't fit to the screen size?
I was trying to make some changes with the "Layout_Height" but doesn't succeeded.

This is my XML code:

Thanks for help!

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/scrollViewPhysicalExam"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@drawable/background"
        android:orientation="vertical" >
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            style="@style/HeaderText"
            android:orientation="vertical" >
    <!-- ++++++++++++++++++ Row18 ++++++++++++++++++ -->
            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent" >                  
                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/btnBack"
                    android:text="@string/Back"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="1.00"
                    android:textSize="15dip" />
                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/btnSave"
                    android:text="Save"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="1.00"
                    android:textSize="15dip" />
            </LinearLayout>

    <!-- +++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++ -->
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) Why would you nest a `LinearLayout`inside a `LinearLayout` inside another `LinearLayout`?? I can only assume this is just an excerpt of your xml-file, otherwise this doesn't make any sense.

2) What exactly is the problem you encounter? The `LinearLayout` is too long so that it leaves the visible screen at the bottom? 
If so, this is due to the `ScrollView` as the parent element. A `ScrollView` will fill the screen by setting `android:layout_height="match_parent"`. A `ScrollView` itself gives an unbounded space of height to its children, so setting `android:layout_height="match_parent"` inside the child view (`LinearLayout`) will make it take infinite space as well. You should set it to `android:layout_height="wrap_content"` and see if that works out for you!

Comment: No, The linear layout is too short so when I run the program on a Tab size the linear layout was cut in the middle of the screen.

Comment: Vertically cut in the middle or horizontally? Could you post a screenshot of that please?

Comment: sorry I'm new here and I don't know how to load an image. 
Horizontally in the middle of the screen.

Comment: You can edit your initial question. Then there's a button to add an image!

Comment: I have not enough reputation to add images.

Comment: then upload it somewhere and paste the link please.

Comment: It seems that android kind of ignores the `match_parent` attribute, replacing it by `wrap_content`. Even if you use `fill_parent` the `LinearLayout` will only be as long as its children are. 

But why is this bothering you? If the Layout would fill the whole screen this would mean the buttons would be way to big.

Comment: no , I want the buttons at the same size, but shown in the bottom of the screen and not in the middle like they are.

Comment: I'm sorry but that stumps me... If it is possible to give a child of a `ScrollView` more place than it really needs I don't know how to achieve that.

Answer (score 6):

I can't comment, so I'll try to answer:
Did you try to set `android:fillViewport="true"` in your `ScrollView`?